# Bidimap size always 1

Tags: java, string

I am entering values to Bidimap. In each loop I am put(ing) values into the Bidimap and I am also printing the size of the Bidimap. It is always 1. I have also checked value of map through debbugger and it shows only one value which is the present value being put in the most recent iteration in the map. What is going wrong here? How am I suppose to save key-value in the Bidimap.

Please find below the complete code.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Read file
        BufferedReader br = null;

        int wordCount=0;
        String wordArray[] = null;
        BidiMap<String, Integer> map = new DualHashBidiMap<String, Integer>();


        try {   
            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\IASTATE\\test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                wordArray = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
                wordCount += wordArray.length;
            }

            //Read word 1,word 2,word 3
            int count;
            String key;
            for(int i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
            {
                    key=wordArray[i]+wordArray[i+1]+wordArray[i+2];

                //Compare Hashmap if the String {'word 1','word 2','word 3'}
                //exists
                if(map.containsKey(key))
                {
                    //If exists increment counter
                    count=(Integer) map.get(key);
                    count++;
                    map.put(key, count);
                }
                else
                {
                    //If doesnot exist push String {'word 1','word 2','word 3'} 
                    //in the Hashmap and initialize counter to 1
                    map.put(key, 1);
                }
                key=null;
                System.out.println("Size of Map"+map.size());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

test.txt content is

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is line four
```

Comment: What's in test.txt?  If the first three words are the same, then that's the expected behavior - BidiMap as the name implies must be 1-1.

Comment: Yeah, so, "This"+"is"+"line" is exactly the same for each line.   So, you're overwriting the key/value pair.

Comment: Bods, it not _processing_ each line, the first loop reads all the lines but stores only the last. Then the following loop only has the last line to work with.

Comment: I am reading 3 words at a time and put(ing) the value in map as follows:
This is line|
is line one|
line one This|
one This is|
This is line

Comment: spartan, that may be what you're _trying_ to do but it's not _actually_ what you're doing :-)

Comment: when i debug my code this is what it shows me after each iteration. the map does read the next 3 words as I mentioned bt the map doesnot store what was read before

Comment: I fixed the problem. the problem was because I ws using Bidimap. I changed that to HashMap and everything works perfect.

Comment: If it's working, then the code you've given us is not the code you have. Voting to close since it's therefore unlikely to be useful to anyone else in future.

Comment: pazdiablo: as i mentioned I was using Bidimap in my code for the map variable. Now I changed to HashMap since someone here mentioned that this behaviour is  because of Bidimap. Once I changed the map variable type to Hashmap everythings working as expected. I am using the same code with the exception of map variable type changed

Answer (score 0):

You're reading every single line of the file but you're not processing any of those lines until *after* you've finished:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    wordArray = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
    wordCount += wordArray.length;
}

// Now you're messing about with wordArray, which is the _last_ line.
```

It's *possible* that your intent is to *append* all the words of each line to the `wordArray` array but that's not what you're doing.

That means you're only processing the *last* line of your file. If the last line is *truly* "this is line four", I'd still expect two entries, one for "this is line" and another for "is line four". But I'd fix up the problem described above before you start worrying about that.

By fixing it, I mean not overwriting `wordArray` every time a line is read in but instead appending to that array.